Replacing a type with a type map in typescript
I have enums in typescript that are implemented with types and objects. I want a generic method that can deal with them in a typesafe way.
type MyEnum = 1 | 2 ; 
const MyEnum = { 
    AAA: 1 as MyEnum, 
    BBB: 2 as MyEnum,
}

type MyEnum2 = 'a' | 'b' ; 
const MyEnum2 = { 
    a: 'a' as MyEnum2, 
    b: 'b' as MyEnum2,
}

Doing so explicitly works well:
function getA<E extends 'myenum', B extends keyof typeof MyEnum>(e: E, key: B): void;
function getA<E extends 'myenum2', B extends keyof typeof MyEnum2>(e: E, key: B): void;
function getA<E, B>(e: E, key: B): void {
    console.log(e, key);
}
getA("myenum", "AAA");

When using a type map, it does not work:
type EnumTypes = {
  myenum: MyEnum;
  myenum2: MyEnum2;
}

function getB<E extends keyof EnumTypes, B extends keyof EnumTypes[E]>(e: E, key: B) {
    console.log(e, key);
}
get4("myenum", "BBB");

Why is keyof EnumTypes[E] of type "toString" | "toFixed" | "toExponential" | "toPrecision" | "valueOf" | "toLocaleString" ?

Interesting. Does this pattern offer any advantages over TypeScript's built-in enums?

You forgot to set proper types for EnumTypes:
Playground
type EnumTypes = {
  myenum: typeof MyEnum;
  myenum2: typeof MyEnum2;
}


If, for example, E is myenum, then EnumTypes[E] is the type MyEnum. This is completely unrelated to the const MyEnum that contains the enum values, even if they have the same name.
To access the allowed enum values, you can create another const map:
const EnumTypes = {
  myenum: MyEnum,
  myenum2: MyEnum2,
}

function getB<E extends keyof typeof EnumTypes, B extends keyof typeof EnumTypes[E]>(e: E, key: B) {
    console.log(e, key);
}
getB("myenum", "BBB");

